# After I set a router as a switch, how do I connect to it to do more settings?

Tags: router, switch

There is already one Xfinity modem/router/wifi  (10.0.0.1), now I add a secondary router (10.0.0.251) to the network (the WAN port of this router connect to LAN port of the first router), wants to connect all devices (including the wifi devices) into this secondary router. My idea is to make the main Xfinity modem/router/wifi do as less as possible.

I set the secondary router as "not a DHCP server" so my computer (client) is getting the IP from the main router directly. now the router is running, the network is working.

Then from my computer, I visit http://10.0.0.251 to do one last setting: set it as a switch.

Now the network is good, all traffics are good, and the wifi is running as expected.

Now I visit http://10.0.0.251 but it doesn't show the WebUI of the secondary router(switch) any more. How do I access to this secondary router(switch) again to do any setting?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you want to setup the secondary router as an access point and not a switch?
By setting it up as a switch I'm guessing that would disable wifi function and only allow access to it by directly plugging into the LAN ports of the router.

Try plugging your computer directly into one of the LAN ports of that secondary router and see if you are able to access the Web UI. You might have to reset the router if that doesn't work because that could mean it's running as an unmanaged switch so you'll only be accessing the main router Web UI.  Don't set it up as a switch after resetting it.

If you want to avoid using the Xfinity modem/router as a router, I would recommend disabling wifi on it completely and using the secondary router exclusively. I'm not familiar with modem/router combos, so I don't know the best way of configuring that, but there should be a way to use it exclusively as a modem and use your other router only.

Aren't you paying extra for the modem and router from Xfinity?
If you are, I recommend returning that ASAP and buying a separate modem. Just use your own modem and router instead of paying Xfinity.

Another option, which I think is better if you want to keep the Xfinity modem/router, is to locate your second router in another location of your home so that you have better wifi coverage and another set of ethernet ports for devices at that other location.